# How to remove /boot from drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

Okay so my fault completely, but while creating a dual boot for Ubuntu, I  realized I had created a Ubuntu boot partition (the /boot partition)  within the Windows 10 drive. I created a 250mb partition on the 1Tb SSD  that was intended to be the boot drive on the SSD but somehow managed to  misclick or something and created a small partition on the Samsung SSD  that contains windows. Is there a way to fix this mistake? Everything is  running fine and i still have the partition on the new SSD for /home  and /root, so that is somehow correct. I did install using UEFI if that makes a difference.

Comment: Please be clear with details; you mention `/root` which is the user directory of the *root* user, and not the root or `/` directory, and also mention `/boot/` which may not be what you mean, as the ESP or EFI System Partition is a directory of `/boot/efi` being a required partition (as per boot standards) and differs to `/boot` which normally is not in its own partition (just a directory under the `/` or root directory; but is often added to Server installs). You didn't provide release details (is this Ubuntu Desktop? Ubuntu Server? what release etc) either.

Comment: Sorry, so the release is Ubuntu Desktop 22.0.4.3. When going through the partitioning section, I created seperate partitions for /boot and /root and /home. From what I can see is that the /root and /home partition was installed correctly on the seperate drive, its just the boot drive is the same as my Windows 10 drive which I'm assuming is the /boot, but I'm not sure. All I know is that both the Ubuntu and Windows boot share the same SSD.

Comment: With 22.04 and Ubiquity installer, you can only install UEFI boot files in first drive. If both drives are internal that is ok, unless you really want Ubuntu/grub on Ubuntu drive.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 You would have to create an ESP - efi system partition as FAT32 with boot,esp flags, change fstab UUID to mount that ESP and reinstall grub.

Comment: The directory `/root` usually only contains a few KB of data, are you sure it was `/root` and not `/` (`/root` & the root or `/` directory are very different things). My current *mantic* desktop system has a 28MB `/root` whilst `/` or my actual *root* directory is 59GB.  Allocating a partition for `/root` makes no sense to me as it'll waste space as even 100MB is large!  Are you sure you don't mean the `/` or actual root directory.  (`/` and `/root` are very different things don't forget)